# How to add users for windows authentication / IIS

Tags: asp.net

I'm porting a legacy (read ancient) .asp application to a new server for backup purposes. It uses this code to determine the user:

sLogonUser = LCase(Request.ServerVariables("LOGON_USER"))

I believe in order for this field to be populated, I've got to turn on "Windows Integratged Authentication" using IIS Manager. I've done this, but now I get an error message stating "The website cannot be displayed". I think this must have to do with authentication, because even a simple "hello.asp" has the same problem.

This leads me to believe that valid windows users have to be registered on the new server. Is this "Active Directory"? What's the best way to go about adding users?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe for this to work the Web server must be on the same domain as the client accessing the web server and the users be created in the domains active directory schema.

The client must use IE for the LOGON_USER to be automatically sent to the server

If you are using IE it may be worth turning off friendly http error messages to see if the server is sending any more detailed information that IE is masking.

This can be done by going to;

- Tools -> Internet Options
- Select the Advanced Tab
- Uncheck the option that says "Show friendly http error messages"

Now reload the page. If there is anymore detailed info there will be an HTTP status code (more than likely 403.x) if you google "http status code " replacing  with the code displayed you should find more information on the problem.

HTH

Comment: "The client must use IE for the LOGON_USER to be automatically sent to the server" -- not true. Firefox/Chromewill prompt for NTLM authentication. IE is seemless, but LOGON_USER will still work with other browsers.

Comment: Is that not exactly what he said?

Comment: Wow, I have no idea what I was smoking/eating/drinking/doing when I wrote that. Now, an etiquette question - do I delete my comment, or keep it here for the benefit of all to laugh at me?